# Spring Data JDBC many to many relationship management

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I have a many-to-many relationship person -> person_address <- address and use a reference class. But in my Person aggregate root it seems only adding person_address works (addresses collection):

```
@MappedCollection(idColumn = "PERSON_ID")
private Set<PersonAddress> addresses;

public void addAddress(final Address address) {
    Assert.notNull(getId(),"Person ID cannot be null");
    Assert.notNull(address.getId(),"Address ID cannot be null");
    addresses.add(new PersonAddress(address.getId()));
}
```

I want to be able to delete from addresses collection and then do a save, but this doesn't work. So instead I use:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "delete from person_address where person_id = :personId and address_id = :addressId")
void deletePersonAddressById(@Param("personId") final Long personId, final Long addressId);
```

Is this the best way to handle this?

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Getter
@Setter
public class PersonAddress {

    /**
     * Timestamp generated by database.
     */
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    private Long addressId;

    public PersonAddress(final Long addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just remove entries from `Person.addresses` and save the  entity again.

[I created a sample to demonstrate this on GitHub](https://github.com/schauder/stackoverflow/tree/main/jdbc/remove-reference).

On pitfall I fell into in the past was to not properly implement `equals` and `hashCode` for `PersonAddress`, which is of course important, when you want to remove instances from a `HashSet` or similar.

Comment: OK, it looks like it works using the above PersonAddress:

`person2.getAddresses().remove(new PersonAddress(address1.getId()));` then just save.