# Using junction tables created in schema within Spring Boot JDBC

Tags: sql, spring-boot, kotlin, database-schema, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying out pre-defining my database structure using SQL schema and then utilising it within my Kotlin code. I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Data JDBC.

Here's what I currently have so far:

My User class:

```
data class User(
    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Users.Entries.id) // "user_id"
    val id: String?,

    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Users.Entries.firstName) // "user_first_name"
    var firstName: String = "Joe",

    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Users.Entries.lastName) // "user_last_name"
    var lastName: String = "Bloggs",

    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Users.Entries.username) // "user_username"
    var username: String = "${firstName}.${lastName}",

    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Users.Entries.password) // "user_password"
    @JsonIgnore
    var password: String = "password1",

    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Users.Entries.isActive) // "user_is_active"
    val isActive: Boolean = true,
)
```

My UserRole class:

```
data class UserRole(
    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Lookups.UserRoles.Entries.id)
    val id: Int? = null,

    @Column(name = SqlQueries.Lookups.UserRoles.Entries.roleName)
    val name: String = "",
)
```

My Schema:

```
-- ===================================================================================
-- Lookup Tables
-- ===================================================================================
-- Creates our User Table if one does not exist within the database already.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_users(
    user_id                     VARCHAR(60)         DEFAULT     RANDOM_UUID()   UNIQUE      PRIMARY KEY,
    user_first_name             VARCHAR             NOT NULL,
    user_last_name              VARCHAR             NOT NULL,
    user_username               VARCHAR             NOT NULL                    UNIQUE,
    user_password               VARCHAR             NOT NULL,
    user_is_active              VARCHAR             NOT NULL
);

-- ===================================================================================
-- Lookup Tables
-- ===================================================================================

-- Creates our Roles Lookup Table if one does not already exist within the database.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lookup_roles(
    role_id                     SMALLINT            AUTO_INCREMENT              UNIQUE      PRIMARY KEY,
    role_name                   VARCHAR             NOT NULL                    UNIQUE
);

-- ===================================================================================
-- Junction Tables
-- ===================================================================================

-- Creates our User/Role Junction table if one does not already exist within the database.
-- This will be the foundation of a many to many relationship between the two entities.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS junction_user_role(
    user_id             VARCHAR(60),
    role_id             SMALLINT,
    CONSTRAINT          pk_user_role        PRIMARY KEY (user_id, role_id),
    CONSTRAINT          fk_user             FOREIGN KEY (user_id)       REFERENCES table_users (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT          fk_role             FOREIGN KEY (role_id)       REFERENCES lookup_roles (role_id)
);
```

As you can see, I've created a User, Role and User/Role table. This is designed to have a many to many relationship.

I'm in the dark with being able to "access" the relationship as a variable which I can use later on.

In my previous "prototype" which had a different design concept I used the following format:

User class:

```
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "user_roles")
    var userRoles: MutableSet<Role> = mutableSetOf(),
...
```

How would I define and implement this with the new way of doing it?

Comment: You tagged the question you claim to be using Spring Data JDBC, but you tagged [spring-data-jpa] and also used a JPA annotation. Which one is it?

Comment: Which one is the JPA annotation? If you're referring to the last code snippet, that is my previous implementation which I don't want to be using

Comment: Ah ok, so this is about Spring Data JDBC. I'll add the tag.

Comment: See https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates

Answer (score 0):

I don't really speak Kotlin, but I try anyway. Please use ChatGPT or personal experience to fix Kotlin errors ;-)

The first step is to identify the aggregates an what belongs to which aggregate.
I'd suggest that you have a UserRole and a User aggregate, with the later owning the relationship.

This implies that you need to add the relationship to the `User`, which is your aggregate root for the User aggregate.
Since Role is a different aggregate you'd reference it by id, and you need a separate entity to hold that id

```
data class User ( 
...
    @MappedCollection(idColumn="user_id") 
    val roles: Set<RoleRef>
)
```

```
data class RoleRef(
    val roleId: AggregateReference<Role, Int>
)
```

If you want to navigate from `UserRole` to all the `User` entities having that role, you'd create a repository method in the `UserRepository` for this.

How this works is detailed in https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates

Also related: [Spring Data JDBC many to many relationship management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72318684/spring-data-jdbc-many-to-many-relationship-management)